# React Native hooks usage with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to create a todo list app, with a Share button that can share the todo list you have. The app is almost complete, the other parts of the code is irrelevant I thought but if needed I can post them.

My state is like this:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    {todo: 'Add a todo', key: '1'},
    ]);
```

My share function is like this - *directly taken from the official docs* -:

```
 const onShare = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await Share.share({
        message:
          todos.todo
      });
      if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
        if (result.activityType) {
          // shared with activity type of result.activityType
        } else {
          // shared
        }
      } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
        // dismissed
      }
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };
```

Where I render the button and call the function:

```
<Button color= 'orange' title={'Share'} onPress={onShare}/>
```

My problem is in the `message:` part (second code block), I cannot reach my individiual `todo` inside the `todos` state. It might be the easiest problem but I couldnt find a way...

Help please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way which wrap all data of todo's in string

```
const justTodos = todos.map(item => item.todo);
const result = await Share.share({
        message: JSON.stringify(justTodos)
})
```

Comment: I tried that way but it shares something like this: ** [{"todo":"my second task ","key":"0.5400277526099981","marked":false},{"todo":"My first task","key":"0.505473938112936","marked":false}] **

Comment: I just want the 'todo' to be displayed